# Display TextBlock permanently or on MouseOver

Tags: wpf

I have the `Rectangle` and below it the `TextBlock`.
I would like to display the `TextBlock` permanently when Permanent is selected in the `ComboBox`
And when Hover is selected in the`ComboBox`, I want to display the `TextBlock` only in the `MouseOver` of the `Rectangle`.

(of course this is an example to illustrate another problem I have)

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Modes}"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Yellow"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Text="ABC" />
</StackPanel>

public ObservableCollection<Mode> Modes { get; set; } = new() { Mode.Hover, Mode.Permanent };

public enum Mode
{
    Hover, Permanent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a multidatatrigger to handle this.

```
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Modes}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMode}"
                  />
        <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle" 
                   Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Yellow"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Text="ABC">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, ElementName=Rectangle}" Value="False" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedMode}" Value="{x:Static local:Mode.Hover}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

My viewmodel looks like:

```
    public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
    {

        [ObservableProperty]
        private ObservableCollection<Mode> modes = new() { Mode.Hover, Mode.Permanent };

        [ObservableProperty]
        private Mode selectedMode = Mode.Permanent;
    }
```